# Ubuntu udev rules for running python3 script on usb device

Tags: usb, python, udev

I am trying to run a python3 [script](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/battle-bot/owirobot.py) to control a USB robot arm (OWI 535) on Ubuntu 18.04.05.

The script successfully opens a "tinker" GUI module that should control the robot arm.

On imparting a command the python script returns the following error:

```
raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret]) usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

Having researched the error I am lead to understand that in order for the script to be given the correct permissions to access the USB device a rule file needs to be created in /etc/udev/rules.d that authorizes the script. It is also suggested that Ubuntu manages rules.d slightly differently from other distros but I have not been able to discern the difference.

Using lsusb I identified the usb device:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1267:0001 Logic3 / SpectraVideo plc
```

I created a rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/**99-usbls.rules** with the following line:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0x4F3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001", MODE="0777"
```

where 0x4F3 is the hexadecimal number for vendor id 1267

I have tried different attributes in the rules file like **GROUP="plugdev"** and have restarted udev using commands:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
sudo udevadm trigger
```

These changes have made no effect on the running of the python script, I get the same error.

#### Update following additional research and tinkering

I wanted to check if UDEV was correctly applying the the permissions I was setting in **99-usbls.rules**, I identified the ***udevadm test*** command but needed to specify the path to the robot arm. This I found tricky, a lot of the advice on these forums seem to point at something like ***ttyUSB1*** but my Ubuntu 18.04.05. does something different. I eventually found and run this script to give me the path to the device:

```
#!/bin/bash

for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] || [[ "$devname" == "input/"* ]] || [[ "$devname" == "video0"* ]] || exit
        
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && exit
        
        busnum="$(udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/$devname) | awk -F "==" '/busnum/ {gsub("\"","");print $2}' | head -1)"
        devnum="$(udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/$devname) | awk -F "==" '/devnum/ {gsub("\"","");print $2}' | head -1)"
        bus_dev=${busnum}:${devnum}
        lsusb="$(lsusb -s $bus_dev)"
        
        echo "$lsusb - /dev/$devname"
    )
done
```

This successfully provided me with the path:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1267:0001 Logic3 / SpectraVideo plc  - /dev/bus/usb/003/007
```

This allowed me to run ***udevadm test***:

```
udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/bus/usb/001/007)
```

The output told me my UDEV rules were being read but not being applied:

```
---
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usbls.rules
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:13
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:13
MODE 0662 /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:42
---
```

UDEV is using the general rules from ***50-udev-default.rules***

For testing purposes if I edit ***50-udev-default.rules*** line 42 to

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0666"
```

and connect-reconnect the USB device then the Python Script runs and I am able to control the Robot!

So now I have to work out what is wrong with my UDEV rules file.....

Comment: What do you mean by upgraded python?  Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS included both `python` 2.7 & `python3` (which was 3.6) so what did you change?  Changing the default python versions on Ubuntu can cause issues.

Comment: I had only python 2.7 installed and working. To use the script I needed PyUSB but it required > Python 3.6. I therefore installed Python 3.6 and then pysub. I now have both Python 2.7 and python 3.6 installed. I used the term upgraded to reflect installing 3.6 on top of 2.7.

Comment: I also do not understand "upgraded python". Ubuntu 18.04 already has python 3.6 installed (python3 refers to python 3.6 while python refers to python 2.7). There is nothing to install.

Comment: I have found that: 
sudo udevadm control --reload
sudo udevadm trigger 

The commands have no effect. Instead unplugging and re-inserting the device into the USB port does reset UDEV behaviour.